# Rails Migration isn't generating the migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I'm trying to make a migration, and its not generating the file.

```
$ rails g migration AddGithubUserToSites
Running via Spring preloader in process 55154
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160226151403_add_github_user_to_sites.rb
$ ls db/migrate
20160222201212_create_sites.rb              20160222222529_add_errors_to_site.rb
20160222214216_add_scan_to_sites.rb
```

Any ideas why this would happen? The only thing I can think of, is I moved the files from another folder?? I also messed up a previous migration and deleted it. Could that be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just figured it out through the help of someone else. Wanted to post.

I just ran `spring stop` and ran the migration again and it worked.